# Linking against included platform lib and headers with Android Studio and custom makefile

Tags: android-studio, makefile, android-ndk

I've managed to get Android Studio setup to link against a custom library in jniLibs and compile a shim with it.  But, I can't figure out how to link against EGL.

**C++ Shim**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>

#include <EGL/egl.h>

extern "C" {

// Code and stuff

} // End extern
```

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := faceblaster-engine
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../jniLibs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libfaceblaster-engine.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := faceblaster
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := gl-tests.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := faceblaster-engine libEGL
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I get the following error:

`fatal error: EGL/egl.h: No such file or directory`

My guess is that it's assuming that EGL/egl.h should also be in `app/src/main/jni`, and throws the error because it's obviously not in that directory.

However, it does find android/log.h, so it must have some idea of where these are, but it fails out when it's time to grab EGL.  Anyone have thoughts on why EGL is not being pulled in?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, you need a thing called Application.mk in the same directory as Android.mk to define targets and stuff.  I just added this to that file, and everything worked as expected:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi
APP_PLATFORM := android-15
```